# Add a CheckConstraint for a related object field in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've two Django models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    is_pure = models.BooleanField()

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=models.Q(a__is_pure=True),
                name="a_is_pure"
            )
        ]
```

I want to add a constraint that no B instance can have a reference to an A instance that its `is_pure` field is False.
When I add the above code, make migrations, and try to migrate, I get this error:

`(models.E041) 'constraints' refers to the joined field 'a__is_pure'.`

Does Django support such thing currently ? If not, what do you recommend?

Comment: Seems like you have to implement this as a trigger, outside Django: https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/checkconstraint-involving-related-model/5351/3